# Misplaced tag edit

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I was editing the [kata](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/kata) tag (or so I thought I was), but I didn't notice that it was linked to the [forms](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/forms) tag. As a result I ended up editing the forms tag instead. I don't have edit priviliges, but my edit got approved.

I cannot flag the misplaced description or revert the changes (at least I don't see a way how to do this) so can one of the moderator or someone with edit privileges please revert this edit?
Sorry for the trouble! I will be more carefull next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and moved your tag description. You can see it on the [kata](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kata) now instead of [forms](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms).

The tag synonyms are set up that such that [kata](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kata), [taolu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taolu), [hyeong](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyeong), and [poomse](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poomse) are mapped to [forms](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms).

If you click on the "learn more..." link in the kata tag page, it will bring to the tag wiki for "forms."

Comment: Thanks for fixing!

Comment: No problem. The behavior is a little weird, but I think this is intended by the tag synonyms. Maybe you can also generalize what you've written for [tag:kata] so that it applies to [tag:forms] as well.

Comment: Ok, I've added a description for forms.